# workaround for Flash 10 clipboard restriction

Tags: javascript, flash, clipboard, externalinterface

Is there a workaround for the Flash 10 clipboard restriction that will only activate the clipboard if interacting with the flash movie? More info here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer10_uia_requirements.html This basically will stop you from automatically assigning the clipboard from Javascript.

Is there a way possibly to synthesize a click into the flash movie from JS?

I want to be able to assign the clipboard without having to interact with the flash movie and I want to keep it 1x1px and off to the side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like my OCD tenacity is paying off. I actually found a pretty cool workaround

http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/

Answer (score 0):

Nope - afraid not. There is no work around for this.

- You can't send events into Flash. You can bring them out - but they mean nothing to JS
- You can make events, but you cannot synthesize a real click event.

I was doing the same thing when generating an upload browser window from flash activated by javascript - I don't think I ever found a work around.

Uber sucks I know